# Windows 7 - how to set up file sharing between domain clients?

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-sharing

How can I setup a share on a client computer in a Windows 2012 Essentials domain?

I have 2 PCs logged into this domain, and I would like to share computer A's documents with computer B.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What operating system are the computers? Who do you want to see the share? Anyone? Certain People?

Comment: they are both on windows 7. the share can be open to anyone

Answer (score 2):

To create a share on a Windows 7 machine go to the folder you want to share, right click > sharing > click share

[image]

then enter who you want share with (if a domain user enter their username in the  domain\username format) and permissions (read or read/write) then click share.
[image]

Everyone will share it for all domain users:
[image]

**Keep in mind, that if this computer is off, no one can reach the share. If you have a Server in place - it's much better suited there than on someone's local machine.**